# Wrap an element like wrap() function in jQuery, with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Trying to wrap each buttons in a div (class='gp'). how to do this with pure JavaScript.

HTML

```
<div class="af-button-group af-button-group-justified">
    <button class="af-button af-button-lg af-button-danger">sds</button>
    <button class="af-button af-button-lg af-button-ok">sdsasas</button>
    <button class="af-button af-button-lg">sds</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gp{
    background: blue;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function fixjsf(){
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("af-button-group-justified");
    var elementsCount = parent.length;
    for(var i=0; i<=elementsCount; i++){
        var childCount = parent[i].childNodes.length;
        var elementContent = "";
        for(var j=0; j<=childCount; j++){
            var clone = parent[i].childNodes[j].cloneNode(true);
            elementContent += "<div class='gp'>"+clone+"</div>";
        }
        parent[i].innerHTML = elementContent;
    }
}
fixjsf();
```

Expecting the dom to look like this

```
<div class="af-button-group af-button-group-justified">
    <div class='gp'>
    <button class="af-button af-button-lg af-button-danger">sds</button>
    </div>
    <div class='gp'>
    <button class="af-button af-button-lg af-button-ok">sdsasas</button>
    </div>
    <div class='gp'>
    <button class="af-button af-button-lg">sds</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vhfvakL/1/)

Comment: yes the buttons (only which are in <div class='af-button-group-justified '>...</div>)

Comment: can you provide expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
function fixjsf(){
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("af-button-group-justified");
    var elementsCount = parent.length;
    for(var i=0; i<elementsCount; i++){
        var children = parent[i].getElementsByTagName("button");
        for(var j=0; j < children.length; j++){
            var child = parent[i].removeChild(children[0]);
            var wrap = document.createElement("div");
            wrap.className = "gp";
            wrap.appendChild(child);
            parent[i].appendChild(wrap);
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vhfvakL/7/

for each parent, we grab all the buttons under it (alternatively you could select by class name) and then we remove each child, create a wrapper div, attach the child to the wrapper and attach the wrapper back to the parent.

Or...you could just use the `wrap` function in jQuery.

Comment: var child = parent[i].removeChild(children[0]); what this line is doing?

Comment: @Hanze: It's removing the first child from the parent. Because the collection returned by `getElementsByTagName` is "live", when you append it back, it will go to the back of the collection. So you can always just take the first one.

Comment: It's a good solution. However you don't need to remove the child. ["If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node)."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Answer (score 5):

While you've already accepted an answer, I had a moment and thought I'd offer an alternative (which should, hopefully, function similarly to jQuery's `wrap()`):

```
NodeList.prototype.wrap = function (wrapper) {
    // creating a temporary element to contain the HTML string ('wrapper'):
    var temp = document.createElement('div'),
    // a reference to the parent of the first Node:
        parent = this[0].parentNode,
    // a reference to where the newly-created nodes should be inserted:
        insertWhere = this[0].previousSibling,
    // caching a variable:
        target;

    // setting the innerHTML of the temporary element to what was passed-in:
    temp.innerHTML = wrapper;

    // getting a reference to the outermost element in the HTML string passed-in:
    target = temp.firstChild;

    // a naive search for the deepest node of the passed-in string:        
    while (target.firstChild) {
        target = target.firstChild;
    }

    // iterating over each Node:
    [].forEach.call(this, function(a){
        // appending each of those Nodes to the deepest node of the passed-in string:
        target.appendChild(a);
    });

    // inserting the created-nodes either before the previousSibling of the first
    // Node (if there is one), or before the firstChild of the parent:
    parent.insertBefore(temp.firstChild, (insertWhere ? insertWhere.nextSibling : parent.firstChild));

}

// retrieving a selection of Nodes and calling the 'wrap()' method upon them:
document.querySelectorAll('button.af-button').wrap('<div></div>');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/562p5gf3/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild).
- [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode).
- [`Node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.previousSibling).

Answer (score 1):

with innerHTML you can..!

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/6j3s4fq7/)

i have modifed the js function like below

```
    function fixjsf() {
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("af-button-group-justified");
    var elementsCount = parent.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < elementsCount; i++) {
        var childCount = parent[i].childNodes.length;

        var elementContent = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < childCount; j++) {           
            if (parent[i].childNodes[j].nodeName == "BUTTON") {
                var clone = parent[i].childNodes[j].outerHTML;
                elementContent += "<div class='gp'>" + clone + "</div>";
            }
        }
        parent[i].innerHTML = elementContent;

    }
}

fixjsf();
```

Comment: methinks OP mean wrap every button

Comment: how to wrap each buttons?

Comment: ahh.. i see.. any way i updated my answer and fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant with [Node.replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild)

```
function fixjsf(){
    var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("af-button-group-justified");
    var elementsCount = parent.length;
    for(var i=0; i<elementsCount; i++){
        var childLen = parent[i].childNodes.length;
        for(var j=0; j<childLen; j++){
            var child = parent[i].childNodes[j];
            if(child instanceof HTMLElement){
                var wrap = document.createElement('div');
                wrap.className = 'gp';
                wrap.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true));
                parent[i].replaceChild(wrap,child);              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vhfvakL/19/)